# npm WARN bootstrap@4.2.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I tried to install bootstrap in my Angular Project by

> npm install --g bootstrap

but i am getting following warning

> npm WARN bootstrap@4.2.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN bootstrap@4.2.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.6 but none
> is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I am using following version of ng and npm

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Comment: Just do as it says npm i jquery@1.9.1 --save.  I see that you want to install bootstrap globally on your system.  Maybe you would like to reconsider and install it per project.  To me it make sense because it is part of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the above issue by running the npm command

> npm install --save bootstrap

Comment: This did not solve my problem. @samir's answer did. You're supposed to pick each of the dependencies mentioned in the warnings and install them manually.

Comment: This answer is inappropriate to the question. The question is about the dependencies, not the bootstrap itself.

Answer (score 45):

Just do as it says:

```
npm i jquery@1.9.1 --save
```

the option --save is to save this dependency to your project.

Comment: but that installs a tonne of code you don't need for an angular or react project

Comment: @ekkis then don't use bootstrap :)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and this is the solution:

```
npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save
```

The system automatically resolves the references for you.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me -

```
npm i -g npm@3.10.10
```

Answer (score 2):

npm installation:

`$npm install bootstrap`

`$npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js --save`

then

import to the react folder(index.js):

`import 'bootstrap';`

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular, you don't need those dependencies of jquery etc.
Angular is responsible for rendering and manipulating the DOM and if you’re interfering with it using jQuery, you might get some unwanted results.

Comment: jQuery is a dependency of Bootstrap

Comment: That would explain why i get this warning, but still everything works fine using angular 11, ng-bootstrap 9.0 and bootstrap 4.5.0 (no jquery/popper).

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file 
search for "dependencies" and editing it to show as

```
  "dependencies": {
     //same lib
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
  },
```

or run this command from cmd

> npm i jquery@1.9.1 --save

Answer (score 0):

you are installing bootstrap globally .you need to first open your project file after that go to cmd and install the bootstrap and jquery because the compiler didn't understand that where we have to install.
the code is for installing bootstrap and jquery is
PS E:\web\Angular\Angular program\my-first-project> npm install bootstrap@3 jquery --save
then it will download and check-in your package.json file its display  the version of your software

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved jQuery dependency with following steps in my react development project

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap --save
npm audit fix --force
```

Result: found 0 vulnerabilities

It also fixes the issue, if another dependency is having issues.