# I am getting following error for all 'npm install' commands after some time working for React project

Tags: jquery, reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4, npm-install

Error : 'bootstrap@4.5.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.'

Does anyone have came across same error? Help me to understand what is going wrong here?

Below is package.json :

```
{
  "name": "wallet-pro",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN bootstrap@4.2.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097328/npm-warn-bootstrap4-2-1-requires-a-peer-of-jquery1-9-1-3-but-none-is-install)

Comment: I have tried all the commands from the solutions of suggested question. But, I am getting same error.

Answer (score -1):

Try the solution from *[npm WARN ... requires a peer of ... but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053414/npm-warn-requires-a-peer-of-but-none-is-installed-you-must-install-peer/49188160)*

This was helpful to me in particular:

```
npm install --save-dev xxxxx
```

Comment: I am getting same error for 'npm install --save-dev xxxxx'.